# disable mouse drag to select several slots on RadScheduleView

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radscheduleview

I have a RadScheduleView that allows the end-user to select slots. I am capturing the selections via RadScheduleView.SelectedSlot, saving those to a collection and the collection is the bind source to RadScheduleView.SpecialSlotsSource so I can reflect back the state of selections. (as shown in the example below)
[image: wantedclickbehavior]

Desired Behavior: I only want the end-user to Left-Click on the RadScheduleView to make slot selections (even if the slots are consecutive).

I need to disable “mouse drag to select several slots” (as shown below).
[image: unwanteddragbehavior]

How can this be done?

Additionally because of the desired behavior…
How can I disable the keyboard modifiers: CTRL + Left-Click and SHIFT + Left-Click (so to prevent slot’s start – end exceeding the MinorTickLength)

Thanks in advance…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION PROVIDED BY TELERIK: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/scheduleview/disable-mouse-drag-to-select-several-slots-on-radscheduleview.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.